# I want to solve this algorithm problem about fiding semicircle

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

In a scenario where there is a circular region denoted as C with its center at (0,0), and numerous points are positioned along the circumference of the circle, forming a set called S, we want to determine whether there exists a line L passing through the point (0,0) such that all points in S are located on one side of that line. If such a line L exists, we consider that S satisfies the 'Half-circle property.' We need to devise an algorithm that can evaluate whether a given set of points satisfies this property or not. Additionally, it's important to analyze the time and space complexity of this algorithm.

Example:

1st example: `(0.5, 1.0), (1.0, -0.5), (0.5, 1.0)`.
2nd example: `(0.5, 1.0), (1.0, -0.5), (-0.5 -1.0), (-1.0, 0.5)`.

Solution of Examples:

1st example point set satisfies half-circle property.
2nd example point set does not.

I want to know how to solve this algorithm. And if you give me more details about algorithm and less code, i'll be really appreciate it.

I tried sort first to solve this one, but i couldn’t get a process to solve this one.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Pass this tests: https://godbolt.org/z/K9cz3o94h by altering only function `isHalfCicle`

Comment: @MarekR Your second true case is invalid, all points must have equal distance to (0,0).